# Can You Multiply Different Probability Distributions Together?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

Suppose there is set of $k$ different countries. Let's say that the average income of a specific country can be given by:

$$X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma_e^2 + \sigma_i^2)$$

Where:

- $X_i$ is the average income of a specific country
- $\mu$ is the average income of all countries within the set
- $\sigma_i^2$ is the variance of the average income for a specific country
- $\sigma_e^2$ describes how the mean of each country varies from the mean of all countries (i.e. relative to $\mu$)

Suppose I am interested in use Maximum Likelihood theory to estimate the values of $\mu$, $\sigma_i^2$, $\sigma_e^2$ . **Note that in this question, you only have access to** $X_i$ and $\sigma_i^2$ (i.e. **you only have access to the mean and variance of the mean for each country**). You do not have access to the individual earnings of citizens from these different countries - only the average incomes at the country level (and the variance of these measurements).

Since the average income of each country is Normally Distributed - I should be able to create a Probability Distribution corresponding to each country and multiply all of these distributions together. Then, I should be able to solve for the parameters of interest (i.e. $\mu$, $\sigma_i^2$, $\sigma_e^2$):

$$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^k N(\mu, \sigma_e^2 + \sigma_i^2) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma_e^2 + \sigma_i^2)}} \exp{\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2(\sigma_e^2 + \sigma_i^2)}\right)}$$

**However, I do not think that the above logic is correct - this is because the probability distribution of each country follows a slightly different probability distribution.**

As I understand, writing a Likelihood Function (i.e. joint product of Probability Distributions) requires each probability distribution being considered to be identical. Since in my problem this is not the case - I don't think that a valid Likelihood Function can be constructed and the parameters of interest $\theta = (\mu, \sigma_e^2, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \sigma_k^2)$ can not be estimated from this approach. This is because each probability function within the likelihood is essentially only based on a single observation.

**Is my understanding correct?**

Thanks!

Comment: I think the fact that you are modeling the average income of a particular country as normally distributed is problematic.

Comment: Some comments: 1. Your model proposal is not usual. You probably make some confusion about the parameters and the observed values. 2.The Likelihood of $\textbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ can be obtained, even if the distributions of $X_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$ are not the same. In matter of fact, if the $X_i$s are all independents, the likelihood it will be, in fact, $\prod f_{X_i}(x_i )$. 3. Obtain an estimate of parameters by MLE is another problem and it is not related to the capability of obtain the Likelihood function.

Comment: Suppose that we must use your assumption that the income follows the normal distribution.$$$$
1/ From the information "you only have access to $X_i$ and  $\sigma_i^2$", the parameters to be estimated should be $\mu, \sigma_e^2$ (and not $\mu, \color{red}{ \sigma_i^2}, \sigma_e^2$) $$$$
2/ The fact that you can write the Likelihood as the product of density functions is from the *assumption* that "the average income of $k$ different countries is independent", not from the *assumption* that "the average income of $k$ different countries is identical ".

Comment: 3/ You construct the likelihood function correctly. There is nothing wrong with "each density function within the likelihood is essentially only based on a single observation".

Comment: $x$ should be $X_i$ in your likelihood function. Otherwise the general approach seems good - you still need to take derivatives and compute the best values.